# Using Moq to verify in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to mock a database so that I can verify that the save method was called. I have a project which saves to a database, it takes a list of the objects to save, and a connection string.

```
this._database.Save<Constraint>(constraints, "DEFAULT");
```

When I debug I can see that the test successfully goes into my project with a mocked database, and that it hits the save line exactly once.

In my test project I create an instance of the class calling the save method, create and create a mock database, and use .Setup for the save method.

```
private Mock<IDatabase> _mockDatabase;
...
_mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();
_mockDatabase.Setup(d => d.Save<Types.Constraint>(It.IsAny<Types.Constraint>(), It.IsAny<String>()));
```

Then in my test method, I call .Verify to make sure that save was called one time.

```
_mockDatabase.Verify(d => d.Save<Constraint>(It.IsAny<Constraint>(), It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Once);
```

However the test fails on this verify. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks for any help/ideas!

> Moq.MockException:
>   Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: d => d.Save(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())
>
> Configured setups:
>   d => d.Save(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny()), Times.Never
>
> Performed invocations:
>   IDatabase.Save(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Types.Constraint], "DEFAULT")

Comment: Show all code of the test.

Comment: Do you have an overload of `Save` that takes a collection of `Constraint` objects?  Because that's what it looks like was invoked according to the failure message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, what you sending is a `List<Constraint>` and you are expecting is a `Constraint` so:

Change the setup to :

```
_mockDatabase.Setup(d => d.Save<Constraint>(It.IsAny<List<Constraint>>(), It.IsAny<String>()));
```

and Verify to :

```
_mockDatabase.Verify(d => d.Save<Constraint>(It.IsAny<List<Constraint>>(), It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that, guess I've been staring at it for too long.

Answer (score 1):

It is calling the save method with a `List<Constraint>` instead of just `Constraint`, that's why it's failing. You can either change the expected input or verify your code before calling the `Save`